# Link Age to AgeGroup Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a client table that has a calculated column for Age.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Client]
(
    [ClientID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientName] varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [DOB] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Age]  AS (datediff(year,[DOB],getdate())-case when dateadd(year,datediff(year,[DOB],getdate()),[DOB])>getdate() then (1) else (0) end),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Client] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ClientID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

I then having an AgeGroup table that has the following rows.

```
AgeGroupID  AgeGroup    StartRange  EndRange
1           65 & over   65          255
2           55-64       55          64
3           45-54       45          54
4           35-44       35          44
5           25-34       25          34
6           19-24       19          24
7           13-18       13          18
8           Below 12    0           12
```

How could I link Client to AgeGroup to show a clients AgeGroup in a select query ?

With the output being returned such as the following

```
ClientID  ClientName     Age     AgeGroup
1         Peter Smith    25     25-34
```

Comment: Can you please show required output

Comment: Done @TheGameiswar

Comment: not sure whether i'd like to live to 255 years old or not...

Comment: Haha good one @Tanner :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, something like this:

```
 SELECT c.ClientID
    ,c.ClientName
    ,c.Age
    ,ag.AgeGroup
FROM client c
LEFT JOIN AgeGroup ag
    ON c.age BETWEEN ag.StartRange AND ag.EndRange
```